# permanent iOS APNS certificate

Tags: ios, push-notification, app-store, apple-push-notifications

I have my App in the AppStore which uses push notifications. I already have a valid certificate but it expires in a month. My question is "Is there any way to generate a permanent APNS certificate which doesn't expire"? I've to deploy server in client premises and don't have further access, so I need to generate a permanent APNS certificate.

Comment: No there are no permanent certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to generate a permanent certificate. A **production** APNS certificate is valid for 1 year. You will be able to generate a new certificate to replace the existing one before it expires.